# Getting Django Apache Mysql WSGI working using a python 3.4 virtualenv on a machine with a pre-exisiting flask app running under the global python2.7

Tags: mysql, django, apache, python-3.4, mod-wsgi

I set up a flask app running with apache 2.4, mod wsgi, python 2.7 on a mac mini. It serves some useful data which my team use to monitor our project.

I have recently developed a Django App with a MySQL database back-end which works really nicely under the test server in a python 3.4 virtual environment with Django 1.10 and PyMySQL and mysqlclient installed via by pip but I cannot get this working under apache.

My Apache Virtual server configuration is as follows:

```
WSGIScriptReloading On

    <VirtualHost *>
        ServerName <server_name>
        ServerAlias <project_name>
        ServerAdmin <myEmail>
        LogLevel info

       # This is the WSGI daemon process for the existing python 2.7/flask project
       # Even if I comment this bit out, the Django project still won't work
        WSGIDaemonProcess theApp user=_www  group=staff threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias /app1 /path/to/theApp/apache/wsgi.py
        <Directory "/path/to/theApp/apache">
            WSGIProcessGroup app1
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>

       # This is the WSGI daemon process for my django app - I've anonymised it
       # a bit but I am confident the paths used are correct

         WSGIDaemonProcess djangoApp user=_www group=staff processes=2 threads=15 python-path=/path/to/djangoApp:/path/to/virtualenvs/env34 display-name=%{GROUP}
         WSGIProcessGroup djangoApp
         WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
         WSGIScriptAlias /djangoApp /path/to/djangoApp/djangoApp/wsgi.py
         <Directory /path/to/djangoApp/djangoApp>
              <Files wsgi.py>
                  Require all granted
              </Files>
         </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
```

There is a line in the httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so
```

Replacing this with the following line:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /path/to/.virtualenvs/env34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py34.so
```

Breaks the existing python 2.7/Flask app and doesn't fix my Django app

The Apache error log has some notable errors:

```
'/path/to/djangoApp/djangoApp/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.

ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

So, from looking at other questions I get the impression that there is an issue running the python3.4 based app and wsgi compiled for python 2.7 but given that this app works just fine under django test server and the virtual environment, I can't help feeling there must be a way to implement it under the production server.

Many thanks for any help

PJ

Answer (score 0):

Read:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

You should avoid using `python-path` to refer to the Python virtual environment. For the way you are attempting to use `python-path` it will not work as giving it wrong path.

Comment: Many thanks Graham. Reading this, I get the impression I can basically only use a mod_wsgi compiled for one version of Python and so will need to upgrade my existing flask project to python 3 so that both it and my new Django project can live with each other. . . alongside sorting out the python-path bit. i.e. running this under apache, there can only be one python version used for apps running under mod_wsgi. Quite content to do this, the module and all the documentation that go with it are great by the way !

Comment: The other option is to use ``mod_wsgi-express`` and have distinct instances of that behind a proxy. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi and details on proxying at http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/06/proxying-to-python-web-application.html and http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/07/redirection-problems-when-proxying-to.html Just ignore that it talks about Docker.

Comment: Pure dead brilliant - both sites up and running !

Comment: Bizarrely, after working beautifully for nearly four weeks, without any changes to the code mod_wsgi-express started throwing 403 Forbidden results - logging 'client denied by server configuration'  . . . Did a quick restart but whole thing still denying access. . . Any thoughts

Comment: You need to look at what the exact error message in the error log says. It is usually because of directory/file system permissions being wrong. Eg., having stuff in a home directory which isn't accessible to a different user. Can also be caused by SELinux configuration on RHEL based systems.

Comment: Is that definitely from mod_wsgi-express though, or the proxy in front. If the proxy, then obviously something changed with it.

Comment: Also, for long running instances of mod_wsgi-express, always ensure you use ``--server-root`` option so stuff isn't under ``/tmp``. Some Linux OS's will go and delete arbitrary stuff under ``/tmp`` if not touched for some period, which can screw things up when instance still running.

Comment: Hadn't done that but am doing so now - let's see if it hangs any more - so grateful for your help. This django site  is a great enabler for some science we are doing here